# how do i select bridged network adapter in virtualbox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridge

A CentOS 7 VM is running in virtualbox inside a Windows 8.1 host.  I am trying to set up Bridged Networking, but am getting the following error highlighted in green in the print screen:

[image]

However, when I try to adapt to the error message by selecting a Bridged networking adapter, there are no options from which to select, as shown in this print screen:

[image]

**So how do I select a bridged networking adapter in virtualbox and thus resolve this error by successfully configuring bridged networking?**

Comment: How are you running VirtualBox? Do you run it `as Administrator` or with your normal account (I assume you're a local Administrator on the host box?)? A quick forum read and `Run as Administrator` and standard running the VB can sometimes result in "Not Selected" for bridged connections...

Comment: @BigChris Running VirtualBox as a normal user did not solve the problem.  There still are no options for network adapter from which to select.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @BigChris The solution was to upgrade to the newest version of VirtualBox, which I wrote in an answer below.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was to upgrade VirtualBox from version 4.2 to the new version 5.0.  The upgrade enabled the Network Settings dialog to autopopulate the Bridge Adapter options.  This did not require any change to the setup of using just one Ethernet cable to connect the two computers.

Comment: Again, one of numerous possible solutions, but valid nonetheless.